# Checkboxes are not parsing out the data I have assigned in an Array

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

We have built a Wordpress filter to sort through pages and pull up thumbnails based on the user selections. The issue is the Advanced Forms Checkbox does not work for checkboxes (but it works for radio buttons and text fields).

You can try it [here](https://www.beyondcatering.com/dev/venues/) PW: Shogun13

```
              $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'venues_post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'showposts' => -1
                );   

                $venues = query_posts($args);

                foreach ($venues as $v) {       
                  $eType = get_field('event_type',$v->ID);
                  array_push($etypArray, $eType);
                }
                $etypArray = array_unique($etypArray);


                sort($etypArray);
                sort($inArray);


                wp_reset_query();
                wp_reset_postdata();



                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? 
                get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args2 = array(
                    'post_type' => 'venues_post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'order_by' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'asc',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                );
                query_posts($args2);
                global $post;
                global $wp_query;
                $countPosts = $wp_query->found_posts;



         <ul class="filter-list">
                $i = 0;
                  foreach ($etypArray as $item) {
               $i++;
                   echo $item;
                 }
         </ul>
```

Comment: Trimmed out extraneous verbiage.

Comment: Are you asking me to trim out the extraneous verbiage? Sorry I was having issues even putting the code in the post. What would you recommend?

Comment: Nope - I trimmed it out as part of my edit.  The "Trimmed out extraneous verbiage" was my edit comment after I edited your post.